# How to use argparse to get an input with a flag argument as string

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I am trying to implement a `UNIX find` command with the following arguments using the argparse module:

```bash
python3 find.py . -name new -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

The specific issue I am having is with the `-exec` flag. Here I am supposed to accept all the arguments until I hit a semi-colon. The way I am currently doing is like this:

```
parser.add_argument('-exec', nargs='*', help='specify the command to execute')
```

where I get all the arguments in a list form, then do a `join` operation to concatenate them all together.

But over here `argparse` causes an exception of `Unrecognized Arguments` each time time I try to parse a string that contains a flag similar to `rm -rf` for instance. I could of course solve this by using the `""` but I would like this to be as close to the `UNIX` command as possible. Is there a way to do this in argparse?

Comment: What are the semantics of `find -exec` - what if your argument to that itself contains arguments that are valid `find` args?

Comment: note the `\;` to end the `-exec` argument. Hard to emulate in argparse

Comment: If you want to accept everything that follows, regardless of whether it looks like a flag or not, use `nargs=argparse.REMAINDER` or the '--' string.  Both are documented.  But there's nothing in `argparse` that will stop at a ';'.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#arguments-containing

Comment: @jonrsharpe Technically, I am assuming that will not be the case for now, or rather that any `UNIX` command given as input does not match any of the valid `args` for `find`

Comment: @hpaulj That works! Thank you. I think I can hack that for now by stripping it. Could you add that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: That seems unlikely, `find` has a *lot* of arguments! Looking at `man` it seems it just includes everything up to the semicolon. You may be able to write a custom [`Action`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.Action), or it may need full custom parsing.